# Show that there doesn't exist $f \in X$ with $\|f\|_{\infty} = 1$ such that $d \left (f,Y \right ) \geq 1.$

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

> Let $X = \left \{f \in C[0,1]\ \big |\ f(0) = 0 \right \}$ and $Y = \left \{f \in C[0,1]\ \bigg |\ \displaystyle {\int_{0}^{1} f(t)\ dt = 0} \right \}.$ Show that there does not exist any $f \in X$ with $\|f\|_{\infty} = 1$ such that $d \left (f,Y \right ) \geq 1.$

If for any $f \in X$ with $\|f\|_{\infty} = 1$ we can able to find $g_f \in Y$ such that $\left \|f - g_f \right \|_{\infty} \lt 1$ then we are through. But for a given $f \in X$ how to find such a $g_f\ $? Any help in this regard will be appreciated.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Did you try drawing a picture?  You can try thinking about the graphical meaning of the given conditions $||f||_\infty = 1$ and $g_f \in Y$.

Comment: I wonder if the conclusion is right.  Take $f \in X$ as a piecewise linear function with plateau $1$ on the right half $[1/2,1]$, and $g_f \in Y$ attaining a negative value on the same half-interval $[1/2,1]$ (say, a sawtooth function).

Comment: Oops my bad.  I omitted "inf" in the definition of $d(f,Y)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $g:X \to Y$ be the mapping $g(f) = g_f := f - \int_0^1 f$.  Then

$$d(f,Y) \le d(f,g_f) = ||f - g_f||_\infty = \left|\int_0^1 f \right| \le \int_0^1 ||f||_\infty = 1.$$

To see the strict inequality, we observe that the second '≤' above is actually a strict inequality, since $f$ is a continuous function defined on $[0,1]$ starting at the origin.

Comment: Is $g_f \in X\ $?

Comment: @Phibetakappa No, as the codomain of $g$ is $Y$, so it's $g_f \in Y$.

Comment: But $Y \subseteq X.$ Right?

Comment: @Phibetakappa $X$ and $Y$ don't include each other.  Say you have the 1-periodic cosine curve $x \mapsto \cos(2\pi x)$, which has period $1$, in $Y$, but it's clear that $\cos(0) = 1 \ne 0$, so it doesn't belong to $X$.

Comment: See the definition of $Y$ carefully. $Y = \left \{ f \in X\ \bigg |\ \displaystyle {\int_{0}^{1} f(t)\ dt = 0} \right \}.$

Comment: @Phibetakappa So?  Why do you think that $Y \subseteq X$?  I've already given you a counterexample.  I encourage you to think both verbally and visually.  $X$ simply means "start from origin", and $Y$ can be roughly described as "total is 0 at the end".  In my previous example (cosine curve), you can start with a nonzero value, but the integral is zero due to some particular properties of the chosen curve.

Comment: Oh! God. In order to be a member of $Y$ first of all it is needed to be included in $\color {red} X.$ That's why $Y$ is defined. See again carefully (The thing I have typed in red)  $$Y = \left \{\color {red} {f \in X}\ \bigg |\ \displaystyle {\int_{0}^{1} f(t)\ dt = 0} \right \}.$$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117622/discussion-between-phi-beta-kappa-and-gnusupporter-8964-).